# Redirect after file upload

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I created Java Backed WebScript that allows clients to upload files via POST. I can successfully upload files, that's all working as expected. 
But I want to navigate away, to redirect to document-details page of the uploaded document, as soon as the file is finished uploading.

Is it possible to call a redirect using Java code, or there is a way to put nodeRef into WebScriptResponse and read it from Javascript?
Currently I work on Alfresco 4.2.c. In my *.html.ftl I have:

```
<form method="post" id="${id}-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${action}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileField">
<span id="${id}-form-submit" class="yui-button yui-submit-button">
     <span class="first-child">
         <button type="button">${msg("button.upload")} </button>
    </span>
```

In .js file:

```
     this.widgets.submitButton = Alfresco.util.createYUIButton(this, "form-submit", null, {
          type: "submit"
      });
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public class UploadWebScript extends AbstractWebScript
{
@Override
public void execute(final WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res)
{
    FormData form = (FormData) req.parseContent();  
    for (FormData.FormField field : form.getFields())
    {                                   
        String fileName = field.getFilename();      
        if (field.getIsFile())
        {
            /*...Some custom code for upoading document...
             Here I have documentNodeRef of the uploaded document.
            */
        }
    }
    res.getWriter().write("OK");
    /* I can put here 
    res.getWriter().write(documentNodeRef.toString());
    but I don't know how to access from Javascript. */
}
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using ajax call to webscript and based on response use windows.location.href.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have in .js file in onReady() function
          `this.form = new Alfresco.forms.Form(this.id + "-form");    
          this.form.setSubmitElements(this.widgets.submitButton);
          this.form.setAJAXSubmit(true, {
              successCallback: {
                  fn: this.onSuccess,
                  scope: this
              },
              failureCallback: {
                  fn: this.onFailure,
                  scope: this
              }
          });
          this.form.setSubmitAsJSON(false);
          this.form.setAjaxSubmitMethod("POST");`

Comment: And in onSuccess function I tried to use response for redirection, but my problem is that it never enters onSuccess nor onFailure function. Obviously it is not good, but i can't figure out what to change. Any idea?

Comment: what is the error you are facing in console?

Comment: No errors in console, only warning _"The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it."_ But I didn't think it has big effect on execution of this functions.